# I have two tables and want the result of query in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables Comapnies and Trades:
Comapnies:

| Country | center |
| --- | --- |
| Absolute | Mathlands |
| Alice s.p. | Wonderland |
| Arcus t.g. | Mathlands |
| Lil Mermaid | Underwater Kingdom |

Trades:

| id | seller | buyer | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20120125 | Alice s.p. | Arcus t.g. | 100 |
| 20120216 | Lil Mermaid | Absolute | 30 |
| 20120217 | Lil Mermaid | Absolute | 50 |
| 20121107 | Lil Mermaid | Alice s.p. | 10 |

Query I used:

```
select country
      ,(select sum(value) from trades t1 where c.name = t1.buyer) as imports
      ,(select sum(value) from trades t2 where c.name = t2.seller) as exports
from companies c
group by country
order by country;
```

I am not getting the output as required.

required output:

| country | Export | Import |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mathlands | 30 | 180 |
| Nothingland | 0 | 0 |
| Underwater Kingdom | 90 | 0 |
| Wonderland | 100 | 40 |

What I am getting:

| country | Imports | Exports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mathlands | 80 | NULL |
| Nothingland | NULL | NULL |
| Underwater Kingdom | NULL | 90 |
| Wonderland | 10 | 100 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional aggregation

```
select c.center 
    , sum(case c.Country when t.seller then value end) export
    , sum(case c.Country when t.buyer then value end) import
from Comapnies c
left join Trades t on c.Country in (t.seller, t.buyer)
group by c.center
order by c.center;
```

I'm using col names from your sample data.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97d395dc8371f581364930c0faf58863)

Comment: This is giving me everything as null

Comment: It worked after few changes